# Design a PropertyChangeListener that listens only to some properties

Tags: java, design-patterns, propertychangesupport

I am looking for a design pattern / solution for the following problem, that is related to the **Observer pattern**, I have already studied.

In my code I have a `MyModel` class. It has many properties.

```
public class MyModel {

    private List<Flower> flowers = new ArrayList<Flower>();
    private List<Toys> toys = new ArrayList<Toys>();
    private List<Coffee> coffees = new ArrayList<Coffee>();

    private List<IBusinessEntityListener> listener =
            new ArrayList<IBusinessEntityListener>();

    public void addChangeListener(IBusinessEntityListener newListener) {
        listener.add(newListener);
    }

}
```

So classes that implement `IBusinessEntityListener` can register to `MyModel` class.

Then I have 10+ listeners that are interested only in **some** properties of `MyModel`. They all implement `IBusinessEntityListener`. But how can I specify (for example with Java Generics?) that some listener are only interested in `Flowers`, some only about `Toys`, etc.?

So How to design such class structure that would support listening to certain properties?

All listeners would anyway implement 3 methods for the operations **add**, **update** and **delete**.

Comment: For this use case I like some kind of eventbus frameworks like the one from guava or Bushes EventBus.

Answer (score 2):

How about an application of the [Extrinsic Visitor](http://web.info.uvt.ro/~oaritoni/inginerie/Cursuri/DesignPatterns/L7/Visitor/nordberg.ps.pdf) pattern?

Define an interface for properties:

```
public interface ListenableProperty {
    // Degenerate interface for listeners
    public interface Listener {}

    public void acceptUpdate(Listener listener);
}
```

Then implement a class for each property, and a `Listener` interface for each property, and use like so from your model:

```
public class MyModel {
    public static class FlowersProperty implements ListenableProperty {
        public interface Listener extends ListenableProperty.Listener {
            public void update(FlowersProperty p);
        }

        @Override
        public void acceptUpdate(ListenableProperty.Listener listener) {
            if (listener instanceof FlowersProperty.Listener) {
                Listener myListenerType = (Listener)listener;
                myListenerType.update(this);
            }
        }

        // some property accessors here
    }

    public static class ToysProperty implements ListenableProperty {
        public interface Listener extends ListenableProperty.Listener {
            public void update(ToysProperty p);
        }

        @Override
        public void acceptUpdate(ListenableProperty.Listener listener) {
            if (listener instanceof ToysProperty.Listener) {
                Listener myListenerType = (Listener)listener;
                myListenerType.update(this);
            }
        }

        // some property accessors here
    }

    private FlowersProperty flowers = new FlowersProperty();
    private ToysProperty toys = new ToysProperty();
    private List<ListenableProperty> properties = new ArrayList();

    // CopyOnWrite so that listeners can remove themselves during update if desired
    private List<ListenableProperty.Listener> listeners = 
            new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

    // Convenience interface for implementors that want all properties
    public interface AllPropertiesListener extends
        FlowersProperty.Listener,
        ToysProperty.Listener 
    {}

    public MyModel() {
        properties.add(flowers);
        properties.add(toys);
    }

    public void addListener(ListenableProperty.Listener l) {
        if (!listeners.contains(l)) {
            listeners.add(l);
        }
    }

    private void updateAll() {
        for (ListenableProperty p : properties) {
            for (ListenableProperty.Listener l : listeners) {
                p.acceptUpdate(l);
            }
        }
    }

    private void updateToys() {
        for (ListenableProperty.Listener l : listeners) {
            toys.acceptUpdate(l);
        }
    }

    private void updateFlowers() {
        for (ListenableProperty.Listener l : listeners) {
            flowers.acceptUpdate(l);
        }
    }
}
```

Listeners can then implement as many or as few of the listener interfaces as they please, or all of them via the convenience interface `MyModel.AllPropertiesListener`

You could also move the update routines for individual properties to the properties themselves.

Answer (score 1):

for any type of *Listeners* have a class :

```
FlowerListerner implemts IBusinessEntityListener;
ToyListerner implemts IBusinessEntityListener;
```

and a listener list:

```
public class MyModel {

    private List<Flower> flowers = new ArrayList<Flower>();
    private List<Toys> toys = new ArrayList<Toys>();

    private List<IBusinessEntityListener> flowerListeners =
            new ArrayList<IBusinessEntityListener>();

    private List<IBusinessEntityListener> toyListeners =
            new ArrayList<IBusinessEntityListener>();

    public void addListener(IBusinessEntityListener newListener) {
        if(newListener instance of FlowerListener)
            flowerListeners.add(newListener);
        else if (newListener instance of ToyListener)
    }       toyListeners.add(newListener);

    updateFlowerListeners() { ....}
    updateToyListeners() { ....}

}
```

and any changes to each property reflect to related listeners.

**UPDATE**

another solution is that u have a list of interest in *Listener* Object:

```
Class Listener {

  private List<Class> interests;

  public Listener(List<Class> interests) {
    this.interests = interests;
  }

  public boolean isInterested(Class clazz) {
    return list.contains(clazz);
  }

  public void update() { ... }
}
```

an in model :

```
public class MyModel {

    private List<Flower> flowers = new ArrayList<Flower>();
    private List<Toys> toys = new ArrayList<Toys>();

    private List<Listener> listeners =
            new ArrayList<Listener>();

    public void addListener(Listener newListener) {
        listeners.add(newListener);
    }     

    updateFlowerListeners() {
        for(Listener l : listerners) {
           if(l.isInterested(Flower.class)
               l.update();       
    }

    updateToyListeners() { ...  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem with this approuch is that I have many listener (as specified 10+) in original question. So I would then have 10+ different listener lists in MyModel. Then I have also listeners that are interested both in Toys and Flowers, so they such then implement both Interfaces and to be added to many lister lists?

Comment: Isn't there any way to use generics here to get more elegant solution?

Comment: @user3422747 i think to a solution using Generics but i not found any. I updated the answer for +10 listener types...